# Folder Size Column on Explorer on Windows Vista/Seven

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I'm a big fan of [FolderSize](http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/), but unfortunately it works only on Windows XP.

Even reading [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/29/5750353.aspx) and [this](http://www.windows7taskforce.com/view/1847), I'm not convinced that I cannot to have a column showing the folder size on Windows Explorer. Even with all "problems" FolderSize worked like a charm in WindowsXP.

*In a sysadmin life, FolderSize is explendid. Before select a lot of folders to send to backup in DVDs, I can check directly in Windows Explorer the size of the folders and get a set of folders with 4.3Gb to burn in a DVD. 
In another situation, I can view in the root folder the size of the bigger folders in the hard drive and start a good strategy of backup/partitioning/transfer to another drive/etc.
If desired, I can tell a lot of another needs that in my sysadmin life I need a tool like FolderSize...*

There is someone that is actively developing a solution to show folder size on Windows Explorer in Vista/Seven Windows? What the problems that I can face if I develop myself that "add-in" for Windows Explorer?

Comment: Foldersize is a great admin tool. I use it all the time at work. The creator of foldersize has an page about the lack vista support http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/vistasucks.html.
If I had the rep I would vote to unclose this.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the solutions currently available are the same. Using a separate program is just not the same as using a shell-extension for Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this freeware [Folder Size](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Folder-Size/Folder-Size.html) it is really good and contains no adware or spam!

Comment: This is good as a temporary alternative to folder size column.

Answer (score 1):

[FolderSize.Win32](http://foldersize.codeplex.com/) is ultimate one. You can use the scroll button to peek in and out of folders and easily find out any deep nested folder which is consuming lot of space.

Shows everything visually. Very very nice.

[image: FolderSize.Win32]

Answer (score 0):

I can foresee any major issues should you decide to build a plugin to do this, apart from the possible 32Bit/64Bit issue. This means making sure it will work on both. There is no-one I am aware of working on a solution like this.

I would recommend that you consider making it an optional thing however. I will however admit I have always used [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) for my disk management needs and it allows you to press spacebar over a folder, which will then calculate the disk space.